# How to remove Python tools for Visual Studio (June 2016) update notification? It's already installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, installation

I have updated VS 2015 Community to Update 3. According to the installer, this includes Python tools 2.2.4.

However, Visual Studio still reports that update is available (from 2.2.3 to 2.2.4) and when I choose to do that, VS Setup starts, but Update button is disabled.

It enables if I uncheck Python tools (due the fact that in that case it would be removed).

VS Update 3 is installed and in Help / About I can see that Python tools is 2.2.4.

How can I remove notification from VS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. [Downloading the stand-alone installer and running it fixes the issue](https://ptvs.azureedge.net/download/PTVS%202.2.4%20VS%202015.msi).